# Gnu parallel - run jobs on localhost (cygwin) and remote machines

Tags: unix, parallel-processing, gnu

I am trying to get GNU parallel to split up a processing job between my machine (Win7 running Cygwin) and some remote machines (Linux).

But I can't seem to figure out the syntax to do both from the same command. I have tried using `-S localhost, user@server1, user@server2` but (localhost) does not have sshd running, so this fails (the job does continue running on the remote hosts).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man parallel`:

The `sshlogin` `:` is special, it means `no ssh` and will therefore run on the local computer.